# How to set column name in dataframe from function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, naming

I want to create an empty dataframe in R in such a way that the column name is defined as an input parameter of a function like this:

```
testfunc <- function(columname){
  print(data.frame(columname=NA))
}

testfunc('hello')
```

However when i run the function what i get is something like this:

```
> testfunc('hello')
  columname
1        NA
```

as you can see the column name is `columname` instead of `hello`. What is it wrong with my code? What should it do in order to get as an output a dataframe with the column named as the input string of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an empty data frame in the function, and then manually assign the column names you want:

```
testfunc <- function(columname) {
    df <- data.frame(col=character())
    names(df) <- columname
    return(df)
}
```

Of course, then you would have an empty data frame, which means you would need to use something like `rbind` to add new rows.

The reason your current approach won't work is that you are actually assigning the name `columname` to the single column in your data frame.  If you want to use a dynamic string name, then you will have to access `names()` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply!  Could you also explain why my approach is not working? it seems pretty straight forward to me (I am a beginner in R)

Comment: @FedericoGentile You are naming the data frame column `columname`, _not_ the string value contained in the `columname` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Using `assign`.

```
testfunc <- function(columnname) {
  x <- NA
  assign(columnname, x)
  return(data.frame(mget(columnname)))
}

testfunc('hello')
#   hello
# 1    NA

class(testfunc('hello'))
# [1] "data.frame"*
```